# HTC One M8 - Locked after Android 6 update

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, htc-one, htc-sense

So, I received a marshmallow update which buggered up the phone. After boot, it kept on saying `android.process.acore` has stopped with `Google+` and an infinite loop asking me to report the error.

I don't know what I did but now I just get a screen saying:

```
*** Software Status: Modified ***
*** LOCKED ***
*** Security Warning ***
M8_UL PVT SHIP S-ON
HBOOT-319.0.0000
```

I'm stuck on this screen and none of the options do anything.

- Hboot
- Ramdump
- Reboot
- Reboot Fastfoot
- Power down

What is going on?

Comment: Can you consider forcefully powering off the phone? Since unplugging battery is not an option for your device, try long-pressing the power button for few seconds until the device stops working. After that, boot into [tag:recovery] and do factory reset. (The OTA upgrade is actually a dirty flash.) Let us know the results.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It does not boot into safe mode. It is currently on the setup screen (after update), I can't get past wifi options. All the google apps are crashing constantly (bringing error report popup), as a result the phone crashes.

Comment: No, not safe mode but [tag:recovery] mode. Both are vastly different things.

Comment: Sorry... Are you talking about the the recovery mode in bootloader options? If so like i stated in the question, none of the options do anything. The phone just boots into the bootloader again.

Comment: You probably need to find the current RUU and run it, it will restore your phone to out of box condition, except current release of software.

Comment: Any instructions on how to do that? I have absolutely zero knowledge regarding these topics.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently discovered the same problem. Here are the steps which helped in my case (un-rooted phone just stopped loading after vacations):

1. I plugged in the cable to PC-USB. Th phone was not recognized.
2. I pressed on the phone something like "checksmartsd"
3. The phone was recognized by the PC and started as usual.

By "reboot" everything was fine. By "shut down" and "launch" the menu appeared again (phone not plugged to the pc). I chose the same "checksmartsd" and it worked.

I have no idea why it worked. I hope it helps somebody.

Best,
Eugene